# Lado cliente instância objeto deletado e envia para o servidor

Tags: java, jpa, data, jsp, spring

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por este problema e como fez para resolve-lo.

Estou utilizando JSP e Spring Data JPA.

Deleto registros do meio de um form que é um detalhe utilizando Javascript, certo? Porém quando dou um POST o servidor cria aquele(s) objeto(s) deletado(s) com os atributos nulos. Não gostaria que isto ocorre-se, por mais que posso validar para exclui-lo no servidor, porque o objeto vai ocupar espaço na memória do servidor.

Já quando deleto o último registro com Javascript ele não instância este ultimo objeto no servidor. Só os do meio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### O problema

O *binding* entre os `inputs` e a `List` no modelo do Spring é feito através de um índice no nome do `input`. Por exemplo:

```
<form:input path="products[${i.index}].quantidade" id="quantidade${i.index}" />
<form:input path="products[${i.index}].total" id="total${i.index}" />
```

A sua lógica JavaScript provavelmente está simplesmente removendo os elementos do `form`, e.g.:

```
function removeProduct(index) {
  var myForm= document.getElementById('form');
  var quantidade = document.getElementById('product[' + index + '].quantidade');
  var total = document.getElementById('product[' + index + '].total');
  myForm.removeChild(quantidade);
  myForm.removeChild(total);
}
```

Como consequência, após remover qualquer elemento que não seja o último da lista, os índices dos `inputs` na sua `form` ficam bagunçados, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="products[0].quantidade" id="quantidade1" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="products[0].total" id="total1" value="10000" />
<input type="text" name="products[3].quantidade" id="quantidade4" value="8" />
<input type="text" name="products[3].total" id="total4" value="800" />
```

Quando você submeter esse `form` o `Spring` populará a lista pulando os elementos nos índices `1` e `2`.

### Soluções

1. Reindexar os nomes dos `inputs` com JavaScript do lado do cliente (por exemplo, após cada remoção ou antes de enviar a `form`). Essa é a solução mais "limpa", porém pode ficar complicada, principalmente quando você tem listas aninhadas dentro de listas. Se vocês for por esse caminho sugiro que você estruture seu *markup* de forma a facilitar a mudança de nome de inputs de um produto comum (e.g., agrupando os conjuntos de inputs de um produto com uma `div`).
2. Não remover os inputs. Você pode utilizar uma lógica qualquer ao invés de remover os inputs do DOM. Por exemplo, você pode esconder os `inputs` e incluir um `input hidden` para indicar que o atributo foi removido. Essa é uma solução fácil, porém desperdiça um pouco de banda e memória como você bem observou.

   ```
   <form:hidden path="products[${status.index}].remove" />
   ```
3. Ajax: Você pode fazer as operações dinamicamente em background toda vez que o usuário clicar em remover. Essa é uma boa solução pensando em manter as operações atômicas (cada item da lista é atualizado individualmente), porém é importante que você entenda os *trade-offs* em termos de usabilidade. Ao fazer uma chamada Ajax toda vez que alguém clicar em remover do lado JavaScript você está antecipando a operação de remoção para antes do `submit` (o que pode ou não ser desejável).
4. Limpar a lista antes de utilizá-la do lado servidor: É feio mais funciona.
5. Utilizar uma coleção auto-organizável. Marquei um artigo nas referências que implementa uma `ShrinkableLazyList`

---

#### Referências:

1. [Spring MVC and form binding : how to remove an item from a List ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859847/spring-mvc-and-form-binding-how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-list)
2. [Dynamic forms, LazyList and transparent items removal](http://lifeinide.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/dynamic-forms-lazylist-and-transparent.html)

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Comment: Muito obrigado a todas as respostas, não sabem o quanto ajudou. E continuemos assim, aprendendo e crescendo.